# PHP output of __FILE__ inside included file

Tags: php, constants

Ok, here is a real short query.
I am calling `__FILE__` from inside a function.
Now, this function itself is in a required file.

Now, when I call this function from inside the Parent file, will the `__FILE__` output the parent file or the file which was included?

Oh, and I am looking for a source where I can confirm, if possible, because my tests here are giving me entirely absurd results.

Also, if this should display the child (included) file, how should I go about it so that it rather displays the parent filepath? (some variation or something?)

Comment: oh, and I can not use $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] since this parent file is further included in a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__FILE__` is always replaced with the filename in which the symbol appears.

To get the name of the file from which a function was called, you can use [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php). This returns the current callstack as an array, with each sub-array containing the file, line and function keys from which the call was made.

You can shift the front-most element off the array to get the location from which a function was called:

#### a.php:

```
<?php

require_once('b.php');

b();
```

#### b.php:

```
<?php

function b() {
   $bt = debug_backtrace();
   var_export($bt); 
}
```

#### output:

```
array (
  0 => array (
    'file'     => '/home/meagar/a.php',
    'line'     => 5,
    'function' => 'b',
    'args'     => array( ),
  ),
)
```

The same thing works without function calls:

#### a.php:

```
<?php require_once('b.php');
```

#### b.php:

```
<?php
$bt = debug_backtrace();
var_export($bt);
```

#### output:

```
array (
  0 => array (
    'file'     => '/home/meagar/a.php',
    'line'     => 3,
    'function' => 'require_once',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that global backtrace will be called at include time and will store all include hierarchy whereas local backtrace (inside of a function) will be called at runtime and will store call stack hierarchy. They may be pretty different.

Comment: @Soaku regarding your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13972544), the closing `?>` is not required or recommended at the end of a file that contains only PHP. You should be leaving it off, please don't edit it in to any other questions or answers.

Answer (score 3):

The [document](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) says:

> __FILE__ 
>   The full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the name of the **included** file is returned.

Comment: hmm, so anyway to get the parent filepath? I can not use "SCRIPT_FILENAME" since the parent file is also included inside a file..

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I fixed this in one of my projects.

**The problem.**
I had the following method which I was calling in the `head` section of my html template:

```
public static function loadPageSpecificStyle()
{
    $directory_files = scandir(dirname(__FILE__));

    foreach($directory_files as $key => $file_name)
    {
        if(strpos($file_name, 'css') !== FALSE)
        {
            echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $file_name . '" />';
        }
    }
}
```

**The solution.**
I passed the `__FILE__` constant as an argument:

```
public static function loadPageSpecificStyle($file_as_argument)
{
    $directory_files = scandir(dirname($file_as_argument));

    foreach($directory_files as $key => $file_name)
    {
        if(strpos($file_name, 'css') !== FALSE)
        {
            echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $file_name . '" />';
        }
    }
}
```

In the `head` of my page I then simply called like this: `WhateverClass::loadPageSpecificStyle(__FILE__);`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge, what you are looking for - getting the path of a "parent" include that in itself again is an include - is not possible, not even using `debug_backtrace()`.

You would have to create your own include function that keeps track of a "stack" of included files.

Comment: -1: it is possible by using `debug_backtrace()` at include time, by calling it in global scope, not in a function (though results may be used inside of a function thereafter)