# How to get name of file where class and methods are called in PHP?

Tags: php

I have two files:
1 - Index.php 
2 - FileName.php
In file name I have below code:

```
<?php
//FileName.php

namespace page\filename;

class filenames{
    public static function getFileName(){
        return basename(__FILE__,'.php');
    }
}
```

In Index.php I called that class:

```
<?php
//Index.php

require "folder/FileName.php";

use page\filename\filenames as names;

echo names::getFileName();
```

**Problem:** When I call that class it returns name of FileName.php!

**Question:** How can I return name of "Index.php" using same class? How can I modify code inside class to return name of file where class is called?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954391/php-output-of-file-inside-included-file) solve your issue?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: @MartinToms No it doesn't either $this or self it return name of file where class is written!

Comment: You might be able to do something with the stacktrace, but it wouldn't be pretty. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with just using `__FILE__` in `Index.php`?

Comment: @fubar I'm working on a project for my college. In a section of this project I need to mention file name but because real file name may change I need to use basename() and because I need to make a clearer code and need to use IF statements before that I hvae to use basename in a spearate class then call it somewhere in other pages.